# Как проверить включены ли уведомления для андроид приложения?

Tags: android, android-notification

Здравствуйте.
Возможно ли программно проверить (например при старте приложения) не отключены ли для него уведомления  (галочка на страничке приложения в настройках телефона) ?

Хотел, если вдруг они отключены, уведомлять пользователя, что в приложении не будут работать определенные функции.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Android O появились каналы уведомлений, данное решение демонстрирует работу с ними. Вы должны хранить константы `CHANNEL_ID`, `CHANNEL_NAME`, `CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION` для каждого канала.

```
fun isNotificationsEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationChannel.description = CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
        channel.importance != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE && NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
    } else {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();
```

Comment: Попробовал, но если даже галка снята выдает `true`

Comment: На Android 6.0, если установить блокировку на уведомления , то все работает нормально и проверка выдает `false` , а если убрать галку "Выводить уведомления" на Android 4.2 , то проверка выдает то же самое что и с поставленной галкой (`true`).